# Systemctl snap mount issue - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, mount, snap, system

For the last few weeks, I have been unable to perform any updates on "Ubuntu Software", nor have I been able to update new software via snap. I can assume it is all related to the same systemctl snap mount error message, shown below:

```
$ sudo snap refresh
[sudo] password for ryanalexander: 
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Mount snap "snapd" (18357) (systemctl command [start snap-snapd-18357.mount] failed with exit status 1: ERROR:systemctl:start not implemented for unit type: snap-snapd-18357.mount
)
```

Another example, when I was downloading vscode. Notice the similarity:

```
$ sudo snap install code --classic
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Mount snap "core" (14784) (systemctl command [start snap-core-14784.mount] failed with exit status 1: ERROR:systemctl:start not implemented for unit type: snap-core-14784.mount
)
```

I haven't been able to find anyone with a similar issue, the only thing I could find with the same error message was [this](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/snap-error-when-installing-mount-snap-core/25307/3), which was resolved by updating snapd. This is the message I see when attempting to update snapd via the Ubuntu Software GUI:

```
Unable to update snapd:
Cannot perform the following tasks:
```

and that's it. I have an image of the error popup that I can add on here as well. Interestingly, `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` run normally.

For reference, here are my system specs using `neofetch`:

[Neofetch specs image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fsbi.png)

```
$ neofetch
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               ryanalexander@ryanalexander-ThinkPad 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           ------------------------------------ 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Host: 20HHCTO1WW ThinkPad P51 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Kernel: 5.15.0-60-generic 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Uptime: 1 hour, 40 mins 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Packages: 3127 (dpkg), 14 (snap) 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: bash 5.0.17 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Resolution: 1920x1080 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   DE: GNOME 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: Mutter 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   WM Theme: Adwaita 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Theme: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     Terminal: x-terminal-emul 
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      CPU: Intel i7-7700HQ (8) @ 3.800GHz 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       GPU: Intel HD Graphics 630 
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-         GPU: NVIDIA Quadro M1200 Mobile 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           Memory: 6874MiB / 15732MiB 
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.
```